# Papaparse unparse config delimeter

Tags: javascript, csv, papaparse

I don't understand the documentation of **Papaparse unparse config**.
The docs say on https://www.papaparse.com/docs#json-to-csv to unparse like this

```
Papa.unparse(data[, config])
```

So far I managed to generate a CSV with a header and write it to the file system. Yet I don't know how to change the delimeter e.g. to semicolon instead of the default comma.

This is where I am stuck:

```
const data = initial.map((obj) => [
    obj.id,
    obj.name
]);
const fields = ['id', 'name'];
const config = { delimiter: ';' };
const csv2Export = Papa.unparse({ data, fields }, { config });
```

I've tried playing around with the **unparse** method yet however I rearange the **data** and **config** objects, the delimeter remains a comma.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unparse directly takes `data` and `config` as parameters:

```
const data = initial.map((obj) => [
    obj.id,
    obj.name
]);
const config = { delimiter: ';' };
const csv2Export = Papa.unparse( data, config );
```